# How to: execute controller method (mvc4) in httpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, ihttphandler

I have MVC4 applicaton, which contains http-handler, and I want to redirect user to my first page

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

HttpHandler

```
public class MyPublicHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            var controller = new HomeController();
            controller.Index(); // redirect and execute 
        }

        // or something like that
        if (condition)
        {
            ExecutePage("http://myWebSite/Home/Index")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually want a redirect (an HTTP 302), or do you just want to send the HTML that the view Index.cshtml renders? Could you please give a bit more info on why you want to do this? Maybe it can be accomplished in a much easier way than using a HttpHandler.

Comment: Users have bookmarked links to local computers, so this type of http://myWebSite/MyPublicHandler.ashx?ItemId=10. I parse ItemId=10 and if item not found, needs to redirect user